# Parcelable inheritance in android caused ClassCastExeption

Tags: android, inheritance, classcastexception, parcelable

i have a Parent class implementing parcelable and a child extending parent also implementing parcelable. My code is attached below. I get a runtime ClassCastException. What am I missing? 
Thanks,

Parent Class:

```
public class Follower implements Parcelable{

private long id;
private String fullName;

public Follower() {

}

public Follower(String fullName) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
    }

public long getId(){
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFullName() {
    return fullName;
}

public void setFullName(String fullName) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(getFullName());

}

protected Follower(Parcel in){
    setFullName(in.readString());
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Follower> CREATOR =
        new Parcelable.Creator<Follower>() {
            public Follower createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new Follower(in);
            }

            public Teen[] newArray(int size) {
                return new Teen[size];
            }
        };
```

}

The Child Class

```
public class Teen extends Follower
              implements Parcelable{


public Teen(){
    super();    
}


public Teen( String fullName, String birthDate) {
    super(fullName);
    this.birthDate = birthDate;
}

private String birthDate;

public String getBirthDate() {
    return birthDate;
}

public void setBirthDate(String birthDate){
    this.birthDate = birthDate;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    super.writeToParcel(dest, flags);
    dest.writeString (birthDate);
}

private Teen(Parcel in){
    super(in);  
    birthDate = in.readString();
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Teen> CREATOR =
        new Parcelable.Creator<Teen>() {
            public Teen createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new Teen(in);
            }

            public Teen[] newArray(int size) {
                return new Teen[size];
            }
        };
```

}

On the server, I create a Teen/Follower like below. The teen and follower clasess are copied to the server without the parcelable implementation.

```
public Follower getData()
{
   if (logic to see if the user is a teen){
            Teen t = new Teen( "Full Name", "1:1:1960");
            return t;
  }
  else  
  {
      Follower f = new Follower("Full Name");
      return f;
  }
}
```

On the client

I do get the Follower in the client code. I have checked by accessing the Follower class methods. It works. However when I do something like this I get a ClassCastException at runtime.

```
    if(logic to see if it is a teen)
    {
        Teen t = (Teen) follower;
     }
```

I am sure it is something small that I am missing but am at loss. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks,

Comment: `Log.d` the `follower` then and see the logcat

Comment: @pskink, I am getting the follower object.

Comment: @AnandSavjani, yes if parcelable doesn't work I have to fall back to serializable but on android for speed reasons was trying to use parcelable. Thanks,

Comment: so how can you cast `Follower` to `Teen`? it is impossible... your `"logic to see if it is a teen"` is broken

Comment: Serializable is alternative of parcelable . But when you are using in bean  than  Serializable is good if you use.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

`public class Teen extends Follower
              implements Parcelable{`

to this:

`public class Teen extends Follower{`

You don't have to reimplement the parcelable in child, because it inherit from the parent. I'm not sure, but when you create a Teen it implements it's own parcelable data-type, and it isn't in hierarchical structure with it's parent parcelable data-type.

Comment: Thanks, I made the change to the Teen class. But doesn't help. This is just sample code. I need the teen to be a follower too. Once it works, I need to add a lot of functionality around it.

Comment: This is what was wrong. IT did not work yday because I had a inheritance issue in my Json too. Thanks a tonne!